# Magento1 to Magento2 Migration Process Step

Tags: plugin, migration, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, code-migration

Magento1 to Magento2 Migration Process Step

Know you free tool plugin available and file both migration

Lets me know

Comment: you can use Magento data migration tool as per answered by Ronak.I have used same Magento Default tool.

Answer (score 4):

**Install Data Migration Tool**

1)  Check your Magento 2 version :- `sudo php bin/magento --version`

2)  Install Data Migration Tool from repo.magento.com  :-

```
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com                                   
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:<magento_version>
```

3)  Configure Magento 2 Data Migration Tool :-

```
    1 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Open          Source platform.
         <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource

    2 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Commerce.
         <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-commerce

    3 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Commerce to Magento 2 Commerce.
         <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/commerce-to-commerce
```

4)  Configuring the migration :-

```
    1 Change to the following directory :-
      <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<migration edition>/<ce or version>

    2 Rename config.xml.dist to config.xml 
      cp config.xml.dist config.xml

    3 Open config.xml in a text editor.

    4 Specify the following at minimum:

            <database host="localhost" name="Magento1-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>

            </source>

            <destination>

            <database host="localhost" name="Magento2-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>

            </destination>

            <options>

            <crypt_key>Magento1-Encrypted-Key</crypt_key>

            </options>
```

5)  Migrate settings :-

```
        php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
```

6)  Migrate Data :-

```
        php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml

        php bin/magento migrate:data --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
```

7)  Migrate Delta :-

```
        php bin/magento migrate:delta --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml

        php bin/magento migrate:delta --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
```

Comment: useful or not ?

Comment: What about migrating modules in magento?