# How to Data Migrate Magento 1.x to Magento 2.x

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, data-migration-tool

How to migrate from m1 to m2 steps wise solution to migrate data and all m1 configuration,
If any step by step link or any solution or Magento tool to migrate the site,

Please give me an idea or suggestions to fly,

Thanks, advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reference Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/266605/72911)

**Install Data Migration Tool**

1. Check your Magento 2 version :- `sudo php bin/magento --version`
2. Install Data Migration Tool from repo.magento.com  :-

   composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com
   composer require magento/data-migration-tool:<magento_version>
3. Configure Magento 2 Data Migration Tool :-

   ```
   1 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Open          Source platform.
        <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource

   2 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Commerce.
        <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-commerce

   3 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Commerce to Magento 2 Commerce.
        <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/commerce-to-commerce
   ```
4. Configuring the migration :-

   ```
   1 Change to the following directory :-
     <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<migration edition>/<ce or version>

   2 Rename config.xml.dist to config.xml 
     cp config.xml.dist config.xml

   3 Open config.xml in a text editor.

   4 Specify the following at minimum:

           <database host="localhost" name="Magento1-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>

           </source>

           <destination>

           <database host="localhost" name="Magento2-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>

           </destination>

           <options>

           <crypt_key>Magento1-Encrypted-Key</crypt_key>

           </options>
   ```
5. Migrate settings :-

   ```
       php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
   ```
6. Migrate Data :-

   ```
       php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml

       php bin/magento migrate:data --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
   ```
7. Migrate Delta :-

   ```
       php bin/magento migrate:delta --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml

       php bin/magento migrate:delta --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
   ```

Comment: Hello, @Rk Rathod
Greeting of the day!
What is Delta migration? I mean what is the difference between Migrate Data and Migrate Delta? Explain here ASAP.

Comment: And as mentiond step 7.Migrate Delta by two command it DONE Or anything else,

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the completed details about the Migration and it process how to do the Migration.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-tool-install.html

Comment: Thanks, @Dhiren
Any other document or guide or link For that?
Then Comment here..,

Comment: This is the standard guide provided by magento. If answer help you please upvote and accept as solutions so it will help other in community as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a few alternative options that I have experience.

**1. Firebear Migration Plugin**
At the moment they sell it as a service, https://firebearstudio.com/custom-magento2-migration-services

**2. Make Magento 1 headless and use it as a Backend API, composable commerce.**
You can save 100% of the functionality, and your sensitive data: customers, orders, etc. For example, this solution will allow saving all customer's passwords, orders, and sales history.
https://sysint.net/services/migrate-from-magento-1.html