# Magento migration (upgrade)

Tags: code-migration, version-upgrade

I am a beginner in Magento.
So can anyone please tell me a proper way to upgrade Magento 1 website to Magento 2

I have required an expert person guide only.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

[Reference Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/266605/72911)

**Install Data Migration Tool**

1. Check your Magento 2 version :- `sudo php bin/magento --version`
2. Install Data Migration Tool from repo.magento.com  :-

   composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com
   composer require magento/data-migration-tool:<magento_version>
3. Configure Magento 2 Data Migration Tool :-

   ```
   1 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Open          Source platform.
        <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource

   2 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Commerce.
        <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-commerce

   3 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Commerce to Magento 2 Commerce.
        <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/commerce-to-commerce
   ```
4. Configuring the migration :-

   ```
   1 Change to the following directory :-
     <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<migration edition>/<ce or version>

   2 Rename config.xml.dist to config.xml 
     cp config.xml.dist config.xml

   3 Open config.xml in a text editor.

   4 Specify the following at minimum:

           <database host="localhost" name="Magento1-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>

           </source>

           <destination>

           <database host="localhost" name="Magento2-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>

           </destination>

           <options>

           <crypt_key>Magento1-Encrypted-Key</crypt_key>

           </options>
   ```
5. Migrate settings :-

   ```
       php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
   ```
6. Migrate Data :-

   ```
       php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml

       php bin/magento migrate:data --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
   ```
7. Migrate Delta :-

   ```
       php bin/magento migrate:delta --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml

       php bin/magento migrate:delta --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
   ```

Here you can also find the completed details about the Migration and it process how to do the Migration.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-tool-install.html